# How to preserve voting results after page refresh?

Tags: page-refresh

I realize this kind of question must have been asked already, but I'm a complete newcomer to programming languages like javascript so most answers which I find here are beyond my understanding. Therefore, instead of some complicated code that I would most likely not be able to decipher, I would be grateful for some directions on what I should start learning to reach my goal.

The problem - as I stated in the topic - is that I let my website visitors vote on one of the pictures with the click of the button; one click=one vote. I can handle that, I have no idea, however, how to preserve the results for all the visitors after the page refreshes.

Initially, I read about cookies and believed that this is the solution, then, however, I remembered that in my browser there is an option to remove cookies, which implies that the voting results will reset for anybody who chooses to remove cookies.

Than I recalled that there is such thing as databases which probably handle such situations, yet I have no idea even how they look, not to mention implementing them.
That's why I thought I would come and ask for some directions, so at least you told me where I should head now. If it's databases I should start looking into, databases it is, yet i'd rather know for sure as I wouldn't like to devote my time to something which after weeks I will find unsuitable to my needs.

Comment: Hello! You are correct that a DB is probably the answer. Unfortunately, this question is WAY too big and broad for the Q&A format here (see the [help]). You should search out some tutorials about setting up a database behind the webpage of your choice. There are so many options out there I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Thank you for swift response. In this case I will start learning about DBs. Should you know about some good (and not too complicated) online tutorials, I would be grateful for any hint. So far I found some website called 'quackit' and I think I will start there.

Comment: I'm a fan of [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/tutorial.html), but you could also spend some time on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_DB)....